# ajax, link_to remote in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, link-to

i am new to ruby on rails. i am following a tutorial to understand how ajax works on rails using link_to and remote=true. i have the following codes.

```
// in view/home/sample.html.erb

<head> <%= javascript_include_tag "prototype.js" %> </head>
<body>
<div id="time_div">
 <%= link_to("click here",  :update=>'time_div' ,:url=>{:action => :say_when} , :remote => true) %>
</div>
</body>

// in /controllers/home_controller.rb

def sample
end

def say_when
   render_text "<p>The time is <b>" + DateTime.now.to_s + "</b></p>"
end
```

i've put prototype.js in assets/javascripts folder.
But i am not getting the time on browser.
plz someone help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the javascript that will update the `div` content with the result of the Ajax request. You can try like this:

create `say_when.js.erb` with the following content

```
$("time_div").update('<%= escape_javascript("<p>The time is <b>#{DateTime.now.to_s}</b></p>")%>');
```

You can remove the method `say_when` from the controller, there is no code needed in  it anymore, Rails will call directly the `say_when.js.erb` file.

Look at this [#205 Unobtrusive Javascript Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript) that might explain things.

Comment: Hey thanks it worked. The problem was also with link_to syntax. I changed it to <%= link_to("click here" ,:action => :say_when , :remote => true) %> . Now it works!!